# ffmpeg video command still with black screen

Tags: ffmpeg, video, codec

I am using a screen capture component in delphi that I will use in my program, by enabling the recording option with the command ffmpegLGPL.exe -re -i% PIPE% -c: v h264 -threads 8 -profile: v baseline - loopfilter 0 -b: v 10M -an -f mp4% FILENAME% video streams with dark screen and audio only[image]

Comment: Share full log. Your command has `-an` so how do you get audio?

Comment: ffmpegLGPL.exe -re -i %PIPE% -c:v h264 -threads 8 -profile:v baseline -loopfilter 0 -b:v 10M -an -f mp4 %FILENAME%

Comment: yes , the audio comes out, but the video doesn't

Comment: Add -report to your ffmpeg command and run. Share report.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NEdoQuD5JIr6enwci7l0SI91-CgAMDl7/view?usp=sharing